# C++ class constructor and istream operator>>

Tags: c++, class, constructor, operator-keyword, istream

1. When using constructor with many variables. I firstly initialized it and then put it to the constructor. With this approach, the data can only be inputted by file or console separately.
2. But when using istream operator>>. I used default constructor and then put in it to the istream operator>> method. But i found it seem in this way it is not necessary to use other constructor except default constructor, but the attributes can either be input by file or console. 
   For example:

   ```
   class Fraction
   {
   private:
    int numerator;
    int denominator;
   public:
    Fraction(int num,int den);
    Fraction();
   friend istream& operator>>(istream& is,Fraction &frac);
   };


   void main()
   {
    int num,int den;
    cin>>num>>den;
    Fraction fra(num,den);
   }


   istream& operator>>(istream& is,Fraction &frac)
   {
      is>>frac.numerator>>frac.denominator;
   return is;
   }
   void main()
   {
      Fraction f;
      ifstream inputFile("data.txt");
      if(inputFile.file())
      {
        cout<<"File cannot be opened!"<<endl;
      }
      inputFile>>f;
      inputFile.close(); 
   //with input from console
      cin>>f;
   }
   ```

My question is which approach should be recommended using the first one or the second one?

Comment: First of all your code shouldn't work.  Member `operator>>` should have only 1 parameter. Even if you will make it right it will look weird: `object>>stream`. Just make a friend operator>> and use it. Providing `istream&` constructor will be a bit overkill, and not really natural

Comment: True. I forgot using friend for operator>>

Answer (score 1):

Write the code that is safe and convenient for you to use.

The `Fraction` class is simple and it has a wide variety of potential uses, so it's reasonable for it to have both a constructor and serialization operators. As a general rule, simple and general-use classes are best.

For a class containing many properties or structured data with complicated validation rules, it might be inconvenient to have a constructor with many parameters (or many constructor overloads with a confusing choice of alternative parameters), so you could skip it and do without. But that would be a red flag for program design, symptomatic of the "god class" problem.

Comment: You could add link to `std::string`'s interface as an example of "god class", so that OP will get "real sense" of it.

Answer (score 0):

Usually numeric values are default constructed and then read from input, because they are very cheap to default construct and assign. In this case, it is just a matter of style if you want to do so or not.

Despite this, you have a major bug in your code:

```
istream& operator>>(istream& is,Fraction &frac);
```

Member overloads of operators like a@ is like this:

```
istream& operator>>(istream& is);
```

Source: [en.cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators).

The usual way to overload the `operator>>` would be to write this:

```
friend istream& operator>>(istream& is, Fraction& frac);
```

Why not member? Because if it would be member, you would've write this:

```
object >> stream;
```

Which is very annoying and useless.

Comment: True. I forgot using friend for operator>>